# Modifying xarray plot legend in python

Tags: python, plot, python-xarray

I am new to using the plotting capabilities of xarray, I usually use matplotlib.

I am trying to move the legend that xarray.plot.scatter creates. It would also be cool to be able to remove the legend title.

```
data.plot.scatter(x = 'HGT', y = var, hue = 'time', add_guide = True)
```

[image]

If i make a separate legend through ax.legend, when add_guide = False, my legend order gets messed up. My plot is labeling different hours pairs (hours2 - hours1) with different colors and the order is very important for ease of understanding.

```
ax.legend(labels, bbox_to_anchor=(-1.15, 2.4, -1., .102), loc='lower left', ncol = 6)
```

[image]

So I am trying to understand better how to modify the legend xarray.plot.scatter and I am having trouble finding information about it thus far. Any suggestions? :)

Comment: Could you provide a minimal reproducible example?

Answer (score 0):

This will replace the existing legend with a new legend that has the same handles, label strings, and title strings. You can pass in any keyword arguments that would be valid for `Axes.legend()` and even override the handles/labels/title of the old legend. No other attributes will be inherited from the old legend, including the font properties of the old labels or title. This might not work if you have multiple legends, or if the legend is bound to the figure rather than the axes.

```python
def modify_legend(axes, **kwargs):
    oldleg = axes.get_legend()
    props = dict(
        handles=oldleg.legend_handles,
        labels=[t.get_text() for t in oldleg.texts],
        title=oldleg.get_title().get_text()
    )
    props.update(kwargs) # kwargs takes precedence over props
    axes.legend(**props)
    return
```

Usage example:

```python
data.plot.scatter(x = 'HGT', y = var, hue = 'time', add_guide = True)
ax = plt.gca()
modify_legend(
    ax,
    bbox_to_anchor=(-1.15, 2.4, -1., .102),
    loc='lower left',
    ncol=6,
    title=None # removes the title, as requested
)
```